# DockPanel and User Control UI with Ribbon Control

Tags: wpf, user-interface, user-controls, ribbon

I have a ribbon control with multiple buttons that need to display different windows/user control in the main area of the window.  I'm thinking about creating a user control for each 'functional area' that relates to it's button in the ribbon.

Something like

```
Public Class RibbonViewModel
Public ReadOnly ucPreferences As UserControl = New ucPreferences
Public ReadOnly ucMain As UserControl = New ucMain
End Class
```

User clicks the Preference button and I'll do

```
dockMain.Children.Clear()
dockMain.Children.Add(oRibbon.ucPreferences)
```

This is working as far as the layout goes but I'm not sure what issues I might run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will certainly work; however a more robust approach would be making use of Prism...more specifically the [IRegionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654552.aspx).

What this provides is a way to define regions within your application where you can push content to live within the region. An example would be...

```
    <ad:DockingManager Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
        <ad:DocumentPane x:Name="WorkspaceRegion" prismrgn:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion"/>
    </ad:DockingManager>
```

...where `ad` is the namespace for the [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) assembly; however it could be your `DockPanel` just the same. This can then be referenced in the code behind as follows...

```
    _regionManager.AddToRegion("WorkspaceRegion", workspaceContent);
    _regionManager.Regions["WorkspaceRegion"].Activate(workspaceContent);
```

...where `_regionManager` is an instance received via DI within the contructor of the object placing `workspaceContent` in the `WorkspaceRegion`.

This provides nice decoupling with regard to the `Ribbon` action which will drive the interface to be displayed for that given action. It also provides an abstraction on the region itself, ie..is it a `DockPanel` or some other control.

As stated previously your initial approach will work. Whether you should opt for a framework such as Prism to isolate concerns as well as increased functionality is dependent on the scale of this project both now and in the future.

Comment: Great answer and explanation!  I will look into the Prism option as I know some people use that here at work.  This is a smaller project that *shouldn't* grow much so I might stay with the user control docking option.